# What's a good xmlns alias for the WpfApplication1.Properties namespace?

Tags: wpf, xaml, namespaces, xml-namespaces

I know I can call it whatever, but just like there is a convention for project's namespace (`xmlns:local`), is there a good name I could call the `Properties` namespace so that any coder could walk up to my code and instantly recognize it? Currently, I use `xmlns:Properties`, but that's too long in my opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally use either `p` or `props`. I don't think that there is a definitive standard for this, though.

Comment: props is ok.  P would be meaningless to me.